# Computing the variables with conditions and print all the final values

Tags: java, math, flowchart

I am doing a program to solve this [Flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGmzZ.png)
to find what would be the final value that will be printed.

**This is what I understand on the Flowchart:**

> If C is < E then should proceed to next condition if true and if false then it should compute and go back to the first condition then if it meets the condition then it would proceed to the 2nd condition then if true then compute the other variables then if false then print all the final values of the variables. I don't know if my understanding is correct.

**Here is what I tried:**

```
 int C = 100;
 int O = 5;
 int D = 4;
 int E = 7;
 int S = 2;
 
 if(C<=E) {
     if(E<=O) {
         E = E + C;
         C = C + 1;
     }
     else {
         System.out.println(C);
         System.out.println(O);
         System.out.println(D);
         System.out.println(E);
         System.out.println(S);
     }
 }
 else {
     D = E + S;
     O = O + D;
     C = C - D;
     S = S + 1;
     E = E + S;
 }
```

> The output did not show anything.
> I also think I did all my code incorrect but what is the best method to solve this?
> Should I use a loop?

Comment: Yes, there should be two loops. A and B circles are the places where the looping should happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the two `if` conditions to `while` loops. You also seem to have missed the `O = O - 2`. Also since the flow chart doesn't indicate an `<=`, you could check only for `<`

```
while (C < E) {
    while (E < O) {
        ....
        O = O - 2
    }
.....
}
```